# Export users without a manager or title, excluding disabled accounts

Tags: powershell

This script is almost there but I keep getting errored out at certain points.

The below give me:

> Get-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'eq'.
> At line:8 char:37
>
> - $users = Get-ADUser -Filter Enabled -eq $true -Properties SamAccountN ...
> - ```
>                                   ~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Any help for getting this resolved is appreciated.

```
# Import the Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Specify the output file path for the CSV
$csvFilePath = "C:\test\UsersInfo.csv"

# Get users with empty Manager or Title fields and are active
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(Manager -eq * -or Title -eq *)} -and (Enabled -eq $true) -Properties SamAccountName, DisplayName, Manager, Title

# Export the user information to a CSV file
$users | Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName, Manager, Title | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "User information exported to $csvFilePath"
```

Comment: What happens if you just run `$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(Manager -eq * -or Title -eq *)}`, have you run this script, within PowerShell ISE?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-Filter` parameter with the `Get-ADUser` command to retrieve enabled accounts, and pipe that through `Where-Object` to filter and obtain objects with `null` values for either '**manager**' or '**title**' properties.

### PowerShell

```
# Specify the output file path for the CSV
$csvFilePath = "C:\test\UsersInfo.csv"

# Get users with empty Manager or Title fields and are active
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties SamAccountName, DisplayName, Manager, Title | Where-Object {$_.Manager -eq $null -or $_.Title -eq $null}

# Export the user information to a CSV file
$users | Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName, Manager, Title | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "User information exported to $csvFilePath"
```

### Supporting Resource

- [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: @JoseTorres .... I tested and confirmed this works but the problem is with trying to use asterisk to find null values with the filter parameter. An easy solution is to use the logic that works as I provided to filter your result set down more for your needs. Happy to help make further adjustment but will get you what you need.

Comment: This worked as the previous script I was using with -LDAPFilter instead of -Filter. The issue is it is still pulling disabled users and listing them. They are disabled in AD and are in the Disabled Users OU. I don't know why pulls even though they are excluded.

Comment: @JoseTorres Throw in `Where-Object {$_.Manager -eq $null -or $_.Title -eq $null -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -gt (Get-Date)}` to the line building the `$user` variable to see if that does it—it works for me. Also, you can narrow the OU scope using the `-SearchBase` parameter and the DN of the OU to search `$users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=auth-rr11,DC=tsauth11,DC=nasa,DC=gov" -Properties SamAccountName, DisplayName, Manager, Title | Where-Object {$_.Manager -eq $null -or $_.Title -eq $null -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -gt (Get-Date)}`

Comment: In case the issue is with needing to specify specific OU by DN or needing to omit "expired" accounts that are not disabled but rather expired as that is a separate property. Let me know if this helps you resolve and I will update the answer accordingly. I'm not able to have any of these work to bring back truly "disabled' AD accounts in my domain testing but it should be something as simple as this though regardless @JoseTorres

Comment: Yo, @JoseTorres, peepin' in, checkin' on your grind, bro! What's the word on that task, mane?